# My Modal Header(Close Button) and Footer portion Won't Work?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my Header:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
</div>
```

and the footer is:-

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-disable-with="Please wait...">Done</button>
</div>
```

But When i open my modal by show modal
my Open modal is showing with disabled **x**
and **Done** button is also disabled

**Why this happened ?**

Comment: Please provide the entire modal code.